# An aggregate may not appear in a computed column expression or check constraint. error while using MAX function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am receiving

> An aggregate may not appear in a computed column expression or check constraint error

while using MAX function for a date column to create a table. Here is the code I'm using to create the table:

```
Create table Bills
( 
  BillNo INT NOT NULL, 
  MeterNo INT NOT NULL, 
  FirstDate datetime NOT NULL, 
  FirstDateReading INT NOT NULL, 
  CurrentDate as MAX(FirstDate),
  CurrentDateReadng INT NOT NULL, 
  LastDate as DATEADD(m,-1,CurrentDate),
  LastDateReading INT NOT NULL, 
  Usageinm3 as (CurrentDateReadng-LastDateReading), 
  Usageinlitres as (Usageinm3 * 1000), 
  TotalBill as (UsageinLitres * 3) 
  Primary Key (BillNo), 
  Foreign Key (MeterNo) References MeterReading(MeterNo) 
);
```

Comment: Please post some sample code!

Comment: Is your date column a computed column ? You can't use aggregates in computed column expressions because they only work on a single row at a time

Comment: Error is pretty straightforward. You can't use an aggregate function in a computed column. You can't use an aggregate function in a check constraint. You are trying to do one of those things, don't do that.

Comment: Thank You Vince for the reply. Here is the sample code: Create table Bills(
BillNo INT NOT NULL,
MeterNo INT NOT NULL,
FirstDate datetime NOT NULL,
FirstDateReading INT NOT NULL,
CurrentDate as MAX(FirstDate)
CurrentDateReadng INT NOT NULL,
LastDate as DATEADD(m,-1,CurrentDate)
LastDateReading INT NOT NULL,
Usageinm3 as (CurrentDateReadng-LastDateReading),
Usageinlitres as (Usageinm3 * 1000),
TotalBill as (UsageinLitres * 3)
Primary Key (BillNo),
Foreign Key (MeterNo) References MeterReading(MeterNo)
);

Answer (score 0):

Since you are defining the table structure, you should put the data type for each column, not the value.

```
Create table Bills
( 
  BillNo INT NOT NULL, 
  MeterNo INT NOT NULL, 
  FirstDate datetime NOT NULL, 
  FirstDateReading INT NOT NULL, 
  CurrentDate as DATE, <--should be the data type
...
```

If you are creating a table based on other tables, you should use something like

```
SELECT billno,
       meterno,
       firstdate,
       firstdatereading,
       MAX(firstdate)
...
  INTO Bills
  FROM sourcetable
 WHERE conditions
 GROUP BY billno,
          meterno,
          firstdate,
          firstdatereading
...
```